# How to install an old QGIS Master (1ab5cdc)?

Tags: qgis, installation

I need to revert my current version of the QGIS Desktop Master back to 1ab5cdc (about 5 months ago).  Anyone know how I can make this happen?  I'm running windows XP

Answer (score 1):

QGIS Master is intended to be nightly builds. Thats why nobody thought of keeping older releases for download. There are some older packages here:
http://download.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/testing/release/qgis/qgis-dev/

but these are to young for your purpose.

Using the OSGEo4W setup installer, all your downloaded packages should have been saved somewhere on your system in \release\qgis\qgis-dev. But you have to take care for dependencies of other packages by yourself when reinstalling those.